# Can not get value from JSON object

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I'm having trouble getting the data value from JSON object. Here is my code:

```
var ab_id = $( "#ab_id" ).val();
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    contentType: 'application/json',
    url: 'edit_account.php',
    data: {ab_id:ab_id, u_id:u_id},
    success: function(data) 
    {
        alert(data.ab_name);        
    },

});
```

When I do `alert(data)`, I got the actual data like this:

```
{    
     "ab_id":"7",
     "ab_name":"Lily's Storage Address",
     "ab_ship_name":"LIly C\/O SELF STORAGE",
     "ab_addr_1":"C\/O Lily",
     "ab_addr_2":"16 PIUMA AVENUE, UNIT #2",
     "ab_city":"CERI",          
     "ab_state":"CA",
     "ab_postal":"90700",
     "ab_phone":null,
     "ab_default":"0",
     "ab_is_storage":"1"
}
```

However, when I retrieve the data value by using `data.ab_name`, it returns undefined.

Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 0):

Use **bracket notation**

```
alert(data['ab_name']);
```

for reference https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors

Comment: Why should this change anything? `ab_name` is a valid identifier name and doesn't need quotes ([link](https://mothereff.in/js-properties#ab%5fname))

Answer (score 0):

Parse your string to a object

```
data = JSON.parse(data);
 alert(data.ab_name);
```